# Clipping Township and Range Grid to a shape in layout view

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, grids-graticules

What I am trying to do is to create a map of a county with township and range labeled on the outside of the county boundary, specifically I do not want a rectangle frame with tick marks and labels around the border of the page but rather around the county boundary.  I created a custom overlay from a PLSS township and range feature class.  Then in layout view, I added the custom overlay as a grid in the data frame properties window then I clipped the data frame to the shape of the county.  I also checked the clip grids and graticule box. Unfortunately this does not do the trick, it adds that rectangle with tick marks and labels to a frame that borders the page edge and not around the county polygon.  I assume that this is happening because I created a custom overlay rather than a grid or graticule.

Does anyone know how to achieve my goal here shy of labeling with inserted text boxes?

Comment: Create fishnet as polylines using county polygon as extent.Intersect with output as points. Label points on the sides by relevant coordinate. Defining fishnet origin and intervals can be tricky

Answer (score 0):

The procedure that you describe should just work if you use the grid/graticule functionality.

By default that gets graphically clipped to the clipping polygon in the same way that the layers within it do.